# How to calculate closed form expression for r-simplex numbers

Tags: matrices

[image]

Hello,
     I've gotten far on this exercise, with the following insight:

Here is a matrix of examples (vertical-axis is n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; horizontal-axis is k=1,2,3,4)

1: 1  1   1   1

2: 2  3   4   5

3: 3  6  10  15

4: 4 10  20  35

5: 5 15  35  70

6: 6 21  56 126

7: 7 28  84 210

8: 8 36 120 330

Now, there is an obvious pattern among the numbers, being triangular numbers, sum of triangular numbers, sum of sum of triangular numbers, and so on. My question is:

Can you help me find closed form expressions for the sums of the entries:

1. Down the columns
2. Across the rows
3. And for general n,k?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* If the print statement read

`println(i_k,i_{k-1} + 1, i_{k-2} +2,..., i_2+k-2, i_1+k-1)`

then the code would output all possible chices of $k$ distinct elements $\in\{1,\ldots , n+k-1\}$.